# How to compare the contents of a column of the same data table

Tags: r

I have this table:

[image]

and I want to get the rows that are equal to the first three columns, like this:

[image]

I've tried these functions, but when I get the index of the lines, r doesn't give the output that I want:

```
df$obj<-sapply(c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3"), function (comparison) {
    df$sample1 == df[comparison]
})
```

Comment: following on from my `dplyr` suggestion on your previous question: `filter(df, sample1 == sample2 & sample1 == sample3)` Note that `a` and `A` are not the same. If you want a case-insensitive matching, use `filter(df, toupper(sample1) == toupper(sample2) & toupper(sample1) == toupper(sample3))`

Comment: but in that way you only get comparison between two columns, you see? you can have the same result between sample 1 and sample 2 , but when you are going to compare sample 1 and sample 3, the result can be different than the previous one

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If sample1 == sample2 and sample1 == sample3, then sample2 has to be equal to sample3. Unless I'm misunderstanding your goal. My code will turn your example input into your desired output though

Answer (score 4):

Loop through 3 columns by row using *apply*, then convert *toupper* case (as we want `a` same as `A`), get *unique*, and get *lengths*, if length is 1 then all 3 values are equal:

```
df1[ lengths(
  apply(df1[, 1:3], 1, function(i) unique(toupper(i)))
  ) == 1, ]
```

This would scale better if we want to compare 4, 10, n(?) columns.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use *dplyr*, we can do this using *base*, see below example:

```
# reproducible example data
df1 <- data.frame(
  t(data.frame(
    one = c("A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C"),
    two = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C"), 
    thr = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
    fou = c("C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"))), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1
#     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
# one  A  A  A  C  C  C
# two  A  A  A  A  A  C
# thr  A  A  A  A  A  A
# fou  C  A  A  A  A  A

# solution, subset using logical index:
selection <- df1[df1[, 1] == df1[, 2] & df1[, 1] == df1[, 3], ]

selection
#     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
# one  A  A  A  C  C  C
# two  A  A  A  A  A  C
# thr  A  A  A  A  A  A
```

Comment: To be fair, you don't really need dplyr for anything. I just think it's easier to wrap your head around `filter` then a command that repeats the name of the data frame 5 times, along with 5 sets of square brackets and 5 commas. Personal preference though I guess.

Comment: @heathobrien, you are right dplyr is a great tool, and I think for some difficult tasks even necessary. For row selection with conditional statements I am used to select this (old fashion) way. But with dplyr would certainly be good as well.

Comment: `t(data.frame(…))` is an odd pattern, since `t` always converts data.frames to matrices, and assigning the result to a variable called `df` is actively misleading.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, that was to make a workable example. I understand that you don't like my style (also from previous comments), feel free to put your own answer.

Comment: @b.nota Actually I have no problem with the style of this answer, I think it actually works well otherwise. But, to clarify, my previous comment *wasn’t about style*.

Comment: @b.nota hope you don't mind the edit. Generally I avoid function names (`df`). And converted your matrix to a dataframe by wrapping it with another dataframe. Your solution works just fine.